# Active Directory Import not working correctly

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, profile-sync

I have configured AD Import on 2013 instance, but it seems that it doesn't work correctly. New entries in specified OUs are not imported into UPS. I have checked the logs and there are no errors thrown by profile sync. Below is an example:

[image: Active Directory]
[image: UPS]

As you can see everything seems to be correctly configured, yet the profile is not created in UPS and workflow throws an error when being initiated by a user presented above:

[image: WF]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Windows Application event logs at the time of import?

Comment: @n0e Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the short guide written 1 year ago.

1. Change synchronization settings to SharePoint Active Directory Import
2. Check “Profile Synchronization status” to be “Idle”
3. If “Profile Synchronization status” is “Not provisioned”, go to “Services on server” and start “User Profile Synchronization Service” service

Enter user name and password, check for timer job “ProfileSynchronizationSetupJob” execution in “Monitoring” – “Timer job status”

4. Go to “Synchronization Connections”, create new connection

Enter in “Fully Qualified Domain Name (e.g. contoso.com)” full domain name, e.g. (1 domain name for each connection):

XXXX.XXXX.com

Choose “Authentication Provider Type”

Enter AD sync account login\password

Set check-box “Filter out disabled users”

Click “Populate Containers”

Select required containers (for example):

CN=Users,DC=XXXXX,DC=XXXXX,DC=com

OU=Users,OU=XXXXX,OU=BO Users,DC=XXXXX,DC=XXXXX,DC=com

5. After all domains are added, check for “Profile Synchronization status” to be “Synchronizing” and “User Profile Service Application - User Profile ActiveDirectory Import Job” to be running
6. Constantly monitor the import status by checking /_layouts/15/ManageUserProfileServiceApplication.aspx?%ApplicationID% page in CA
7. In case of errors, check ULS logs

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory Import (ADI) doesn't use FIM service. Moreover when you switch to ADI, the FIM service will be shut down.

There is a step-by-step [MS Technet article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meacoex/2013/08/04/step-by-step-active-directory-import-for-sharepoint-2013/), that explains, how to configure User Profile Synchronization Service to use ADI. My experience is, that a lot of problems are caused by the fact, that the service account is not properly configured on the AD end.

Comment: You should avoid posting this as an answer.

Comment: I don't have sufficient reputation on this forum to add a comment to the answer.

Comment: Stealing this from @Guarravs: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the AD import, please try out the below steps and check if this addresses the import issue.

1. Try doing an AD Import using the IP address of the Domain Controller.
2. Go to Admin-> Active Directory-> Import Requesters from Active Directory-> Import Now. This will give the list of all the OUs in your AD. On the top right side of this window, you will see an option that says Fetch OUs from AD again/Refresh. Please click on this link and then try doing an Import and check if the issue persists.
3. If you still have the same problem please restart the Service Desk Plus service once, connect to the database and run the queries given below. Restart the Services and then try doing an AD Import.