# User Profile ActiveDirectory Import Job never run

Tags: 2016, ups

We are using SP2016 standard on-premise. We can setup user profile import successfully and all users are imported at first time setup. However when I check the timer job `User Profile ActiveDirectory Import Job` the last run time is always "N/A". If I click `Start Profile Sync` it seems nothing happens. The status is always Idle even though I refreshed the page.

The problem is I found some users have their Display Name updated. But in user profile their account is still using the old value.

Could you advise what could be wrong?

Comment: Any messages from ULS?

Comment: No i cannot anything.  Looks like nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure will that be the case but I cannot put so much code in the comment.
So it is quite likely that there is some problem with the timer job on the server that is running the UPS.

Timer  service may be running but have no instance (I found out about that when solutions were not deploying to one of the servers)

```
$farm  = Get-SPFarm 
$disabledTimers = $farm.TimerService.Instances | where {$_.Status -ne "Online"} 
if ($disabledTimers -ne $null) 
{ 
    foreach ($timer in $disabledTimers) 
    { 
        Write-Host "Timer service instance on server " $timer.Server.Name " is not Online. Current status:" $timer.Status 
        Write-Host "Attempting to set the status of the service instance to online" 
        $timer.Status = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPObjectStatus]::Online 
        $timer.Update() 
    } 
} 
else 
{ 
    Write-Host "All Timer Service Instances in the farm are online! No problems found" 
}
```

REF: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/1c8bda47-5be9-4412-a531-1706bf0df6e6/wsp-not-getting-deployed-in-all-servers-in-our-sharepoint-2013-farm?forum=sharepointadmin

Comment: I checked the timer cache folder. There are many up-to-date files generated. Could I say the timer job service s running?

Comment: Probably yes, but running the script will tell you for sure.

Comment: I run the script and no problem found. Do you know anywhere I can check the log of AD import?

Comment: I checked in user profile database [UserProfile_Full] table. All users have last update date = the date we install SharePoint. Tested manually update in User profile and works. So we can isolate the sync is not working by some reason.

Comment: Check the second answer from this question: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164858/active-directory-import-not-working-correctly. Specifically see the UP Sync service is running on the server.

Comment: Inspired by your answer, I found a work around. Refer to old discussion (https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231887/sharepoint-2010-timer-service-is-started-but-the-timer-jobs-are-not-running) Waqas answer. I run PS like below:
foreach ($ft in $FarmTimers) .... $ft.AllowServiceJobs = $true; $ft.Update();

Comment: However it is just work around because on everyday around 6am the AllowServiceJobs will become false again. Not sure what is happening

Comment: This is a new setting I wasn't aware of it, thanks for sharing. Check this question maybe it will help you to see why this is happening. You can write a small watcher for that property to and query it each 30 sec to know exatctly when it is being changed. Than use this suggestion to see what is causing it . https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/270449/timer-jobs-not-running-due-to-allowservicejobs-and-allowcontentdatabasejobs-bein

Comment: job-timer-recycle run daily at 6am. It seems the this job reset everything

Comment: I think at this point I would open a ticket with Microsoft and in the meantime I set a scheduled script to run after 6 am to enable the service jobs.